# SQL select between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i looking for a query that get records between two dates

Start-date should be `OrderDate` + 28 days

End-date should be result of Start-date + 4 days

Select query

```
SELECT dbo.Orders.*, dbo.Customer.* FROM dbo.Orders INNER JOIN dbo.Customer ON dbo.Orders.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
```

Comment: Been solved on SO before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [DATEADD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) fundtion

```
SELECT dbo.Orders.*, dbo.Customer.* 
FROM dbo.Orders INNER JOIN dbo.Customer ON dbo.Orders.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID 
WHERE [Start-date] DATEADD(day,28,OrderDate) AND [End-date] = DATEADD(day,4,[Start-date])
```